# Fast searching in ngram index

Tags: python, n-gram

i'm writing a program in python that finds the most similar words given an input word (using the edit distance algorithm). It must work like this:

```
input = "tree"

output = [ "free", "trek", "trie" ]
```

For now I extracted all the ngrams from a lexicon and associated all of them to the words they were extracted from. I have a dictionary where the keys are the ngrams and the values are lists of associated words, like this:

"mag" : [ "magic", "magazine", "magnetic", "magistrate", "pilgrimage" ]

When I have an input word I extract the ngrams from it and iterate over the keys in the dictionary to find them and extract the associated lists with words. On those lists I use edit distance to get the words I need.
It works well but it takes a lot of time. Sometimes it arrives at 8/10 seconds for just one word.
How do I make the process faster ? I actually want a conceptual solution. I used this "ngram index" approach because using edit distance for every word in the lexicon was much slower. Now I want something faster than my current method

```
def searchIndex(myString, n, index):
ngs = toNgrams(myString)
found=[]
ngIndex = NGram(index)
ngNgrams = NGram(ngs)

a = timer()
commonNgrams = ngIndex.intersection(ngNgrams)
for i in commonNgrams:
    for k in index[i]:
        if ed(myString, k) < 2 and k not in found:
            found.append(k)
b = timer()
time = b-a
return found, time
```

Comment: Can you use cProfile and pinpoint exactly what's too slow?

Comment: @gregory  [results](https://imgur.com/a/wBhYGqo)  I highlighted the functions that take too much time. As you can see it takes 95 seconds to search for 14 words. It is a bit long in my opinion. The second image shows the output of the program , the numbers are the time needed for each word. If the word is longer it could take even 15 seconds for the program to find the desired result...

Comment: What's going on in EndDistance?

Comment: Just keep in mind that ngram-comparison is usually not a metric and as such incompatible with Levensthein distance. You may miss results in corner cases. As for the ngram dictionary you may consider using Lucene/Solr/Elasticsearch for this, letting the well tuned machinery do your ngram lookup.

Comment: it checks the distance between two strings and see how similar they are

Comment: @Harald i use ngrams only to cut down the number of words on which i use edit distance. Are you saying i can't do that ?  I'll take a look at Lucene/Solr/Elasticsearch, thank you

Comment: @Zethel yes you can do this, cut down on the candidate words. Just make sure that you don't cut the candidates down too much or, put another way, if words a and b are within your targeted edit distance, make sure your ngram-preselection is guaranteed not to cut them out beforehand.